Is there a switch in AUCTeX's TOC mode to ignore commented headings?
When using TOC mode with C-c =, I get all the LaTeX headings of the whole document listed, including

those commented out and even
those from documents included via \input or \include when the latter are commented out.

While this is fine in general, in larger documents, it can be useful at times to ignore headings from these two categories (particularly, 2.), at least using a switch or a setting. Thanks for any hints.
UPDATE: As pointed out category 1 can tackled by C-c = r
However, I'm giving an example that shows the behavior for category 2.
Create a file external.tex with
\section{There}

and a file internal.tex with
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
\section{Here} % <== % + C-c = r removes "Here" from *toc*
\input{external} % <== Commenting this line won't remove "There" from *toc*
\end{document}


As you can find out with C-h k C-c =, C-c = is bound to reftex-tocwhich produces a *toc* buffer with this header:
TABLE-OF-CONTENTS on /tmp/foo10.tex
SPC=view TAB=goto RET=goto+hide [q]uit [r]escan [l]abels [f]ollow [x]r [?]Help
------------------------------------------------------------------------------

Pressing r rescans the document and refreshes the buffer after making changes (e.g. commenting out things). You can make sure that the *toc* is up-to-date by calling reftex-toc with a C-u argument: C-u C-c =. The doc string of the function (C-h f reftex-toc) says:
Show the table of contents for the current document.
When called with a raw C-u prefix, rescan the document first.


Thanks, @NickD. The rescan swiftly works for category 1 alone but does not seem to work for category 2. I'm using AUCTeX 14.0.7. I added a MWE to make the problem clearer. Please, do feel free to edit your answer or my OP. BTW: Sorry, it's C-c =, not C-= (my fault from the OP).

Thanks - fixed the key sequence mistake. But I don't have a problem with category 2: commenting out and rescanning (or C-u C-c =) gets rid of the extra entry.

Thanks for trying. This is strange, so there seems to be something with my .emacs, perhaps ... I'll need to check whether this happens with a plain emacs config.

I tried it with my .emacs completely removed, I even de-installed helm and updated AUCTeX. I can still reproduce the problem with a bare-metal Emacs 28.2 and AUCTeX 14.0.7 on my Linux Mint machine (latex-mode and reftex-mode enabled). Please, may I ask which setting you are running on?

I recommend that you update your emacs to latest stable (currently 29.4, released 2024-06-22). My AUCTeX is a bit behind: 14.0.6.

With the help of NickD's answer, I was able to pin down this issue as being a potential bug resulting from my slightly outdated LMDE6 setting (rather old Emacs 28.2 with rather new AUCTeX 14.0.7).  An update to Emacs 29.4 resolved the issue.
Just in case you happen to be on LMDE6, here's what I did: I followed this guide which also works for LMDE6 to "backport" my system to Emacs 29.4 and the issue is gone. For the few folks experiencing this very specific issue as well: Make sure you (i) enable deb-src URLs via the cinnamon-settings tool, (ii) uninstall Emacs 28.2 (e.g. via synaptics) before following the above guide, and (iii) pick the right configure options: I used the one from the guide but with --with-x-toolkit=gtk3.

Generally speaking, you can build and install a newer emacs on a system with an older emacs installed in /usr/bin: the one you build gets installed in /usr/local/bin with supporting files in /usr/local/{lib,libexec,share} and the two can coexist peacefully (I do that all the time on my Fedora 40 system: /usr/bin/emacs is 29.4 and I build a bleeding-edge emacs every couple of months that gets installed in /usr/local). I also don't think that this problems could have anything to do with configure options (but I'm not willing to bet my life on that :-) )

Thanks, @NickD for generalising this answer a little. I agree, configure options are not really important here.
